# Windows 11 pycocotools package installation error

Tags: python

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

I have installed C++ build tools and more.

Install Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126 with default selection. This cannot be install.

Thank you for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already installed Visual C++ Latest Build Tools
from Visual Studio 2022 Build Tools: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe

Now, Check the Pycocotools/PythonAPI folder and modify the `setup.py` file
change these couple of lines as the following code and run this command again

Previously :

`extra_compile_args=['-Wno-cpp', '-Wno-unused-function', '-std=c99']`

Remove `'-Wno-cpp', '-Wno-unused-function'` from the `ext_modules` Extension in `setup.py`

Only keep `'-std=c99'`, and it will look like this.

`extra_compile_args=['-std=c99']`

Now run this command once again.

`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`
this should successfully build the pycocotools in windows 11.

Comment: 'math.h': No such file or directory : i added to commond directory   Ignoring unknown  '-std=c99' option   and again cl.exe error  thank you